# Life Counter Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, count

I was builiding lately life counter and i can't figure out what the issue around here, I mean i got 2 divs, when you on div with class "alive" you get score up and when you in "dead" div you get score down.

Now I've made this code that work on seconds, but it not working stright, I mean 1, 2, 3. But it working like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Tby5/

Or as visual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Alive - Dead</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var l = 1;
            var good = " Excelent!";
            var bad = " OH NO!";
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#alive').hover(function () {
                    if (l > 100) {
                        window.clearTimeout("tim");
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = "Life: " + l + good;
                        l++;
                        var tim = window.setTimeout("count()", 1000);
                    }
                    count();
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#dead').hover(function () {
                    if (l < 0) {
                        window.clearTimeout("tim");
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = "Life: " + l + bad;
                        l--;
                        var tim = window.setTimeout("count()", 1000);
                    }
                    count();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: red;
            }
            .dead {
                cursor: url(thumb-down.cur) 6 6, auto;
                padding-bottom: 285px;
            }
            .alive {
                background: #32ff0a;
                height: 300px;
                margin: -8px;
                cursor: url(thumb-up.cur) 6 6, auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="alive" id="alive">
        Stay here to survive!
        </div>
        <div class="dead" id="dead">
        <br />
        Stay away from dead area!
        </div>
        <div id="percent"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my question is how can i fix this to get it 1,2,3 (replace 1 with 2 and 3, 4...)?

Comment: There is no function called "count".  That's not how you clear timeouts.

Comment: Oh lol, i accediently remove it and forgot delete it, but i'm not sure what to set in timeout now if it not count(), should i make function? and if i dot how can i make it automaticly working without button.

Comment: Please tell me if i understand your question correct. you want to give counter to User if counter reaches 100 "its Good" if user goes to bad area .. then counter is reduced?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see the counter isn't working currectly.. it got issues too, if you can fiddle it, that be awesome..

Comment: @yotam see my answer .. it has link to jsfiddle too. if thats not what you want let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution to your problem. 
Problem in your code is... Hover function is calulated only when Mouse enters... Not as long as mouse remains inside.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vdq39/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var good = " Excelent!";
    var bad = " OH NO!";
    var tim;
    var counter = 0;

    function count() {
        counter++;
        document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = "Life: " + counter + good;
        if (counter > 100) {
            window.clearInterval(tim);
        } 
    }

    function countDown() {
        counter--;
        document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = "Life: " + counter + bad;
        if (counter < 0) {
            window.clearInterval(tim);
        } 

    }
    $('#alive').hover(function () {
        if (counter > 100) {
            window.clearInterval(tim);
        } else {
            tim = window.setInterval(count, 1000);
        }
    }, function () {
        window.clearInterval(tim);
    });

    $('#dead').hover(function () {

        if (counter < 0) {
            window.clearInterval(tim);
        } else {
            tim = window.setInterval(countDown, 1000);
        }

    },

    function () {
        window.clearInterval(tim);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a `count` function, make one

And you clear a timeout using the variable itself not its name

`window.clearTimeout(tim);`

also with your current code you will need to use a global variable

`window.tim = window.setTimeout("count()", 1000);`

`window.clearTimeout(window.tim);`

otherwise the clearTimeout wont see it.

Comment: So i delete count() function from setTimeout?

Comment: I deleted count() function, still not working.. it make the same thing.

Comment: Can you please make me a fiddle, made a function and it outpost the numbers as 100 and 0 only.
EDIT: Thanks for your help, i will make sure to accept your answer.